# Windows page file

Tags: windows-7, swap, pagefile

I'm working on some CGI and am running out of RAM as well as page file space. However I have a second drive with a little extra space I could use for swapping. I have one question:

If the swap space is spread across multiple drives, will all of it be accessible to a single application?

Thanks.

[edit]

Windows 7 x64, 3GB RAM

Comment: FYI: Windows will not automatically add swap space to a second drive you have to do it manually.

Comment: I configured two 40GB swap files. One on each of two partitions.

Comment: Just get a cheap 1tb hard drive and make it all swap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all virtual memory is available no matter which drive the page file or application is on.